# instance variable initialization in Singleton class

Tags: java, singleton

I have a simple **singleton** class:

```
public class MySingleton {
  private MyManager mManager;
  private static MySingleton mInstance;

  private MySingleton() {
  }

  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
     if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton();
     }
     return mInstance;
  }

  public MyManager getManagerByName(String name) {
     //I don’t show the GET_MGR function, it is a 3rd party library function
     mManager = GET_MGR(name); 
  }

  public void doTask() {
     mManager.startTask();
  }

}
```

Then, In another class A, I execute code:

```
String name = “John”;
MyManager mgr = MySingleton.getInstance().getManagerByName(name);
```

Above code works fine.

In another class B, I execute code:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().doTask();
```

Above code throws **NullPointerException**, with `mManager` is null in doTask().

Why? I mean it is a singleton, if I already get the `mManager` with `MySingleton.getInstance().getManagerByName(name);` in class A, the single instance should already have `mManager` initialized. why the `mManager` is null when execute in class B?

I don't want to initialize `mManager` from constructor, How to fix this problem?

**====== update ====**

I double checked, the order is correct, code in class A is always running before code in class B. But I realized that code in class A is running in a different process. I am simulating my real project with above code, so in reality, class A and B have to be running in different processes. So, with this has been said, how could I fix this problem ?

Comment: The OP already said it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Are you sure `MyManager mgr = MySingleton.getInstance().getManagerByName(name);` is executed before `MySingleton.getInstance().doTask();`?

Comment: Can you post the actual code that compiles? `getManagerByName` has a return type but no return statement.

Comment: @ Eran, yes, I am pretty sure. I have logs.

Comment: WHY downvote? Is my question a trash ? I can't believe it.

Comment: you should rethink your structure, are you really needs singleton? functionality of your class might depends on provided `MyManager` which can be change in runtime, and that might be risky especially in multithreading application

Comment: you can try with eager initialization. try to initialize at declared statement only.

Comment: can you show stacktrace??

Answer (score 0):

The code should work as you intend it to. I suspect something else is wrong in the code that you have not included in your question.

Presumably you got the order of actions messed up, i.e.

```
MySingleton.getInstance().doTask();
```

is executed before

```
MySingleton.getInstance().getManagerByName(name);
```

**Update:** I tried out your code, and it works fine: http://ideone.com/a7BULg

**Update 2:**

> But I realized that code in class A is running in a different process. Could that be the real cause?

If you by different process mean a different JVM, then yes, that's definitely the problem. The scope of the singleton is within the JVM. Two JVMs = Two singleton instances.

Comment: My log shows it is in right order, that's why I don't understand, that's why I post a question. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Double-check that your logs are flushed properly to make sure the order actually reflects what happens.

Comment: Answer updated. I tried out the code you posted, and it works fine: http://ideone.com/a7BULg  Recheck all your assumptions.

Comment: Hi, I double checked, the order is correct. But I noticed class A & class B are running in different processes. Could that be the real cause?

Comment: Different java processes? Well then that's definitely the problem. The scope of the singleton is within the JVM.

Comment: Ok, if they have to be running in two processes, could there be a solution to fix this problem then?

Comment: No simple one as I see it. If you want to share the singleton / manager object you'd have to resort to RMI for instance. I would encourage you to rethink your design. :-/ Perhaps you should roll your own server / client?

Comment: user842225, is your question answered? If yes, please consider accepting, otherwise, please elaborate the question.

Answer (score 0):

GET_MGR(name) could return null as well.